# Unable to see Desktop in 12.10 after installing AMD Catalyst

Tags: nvidia, ati, gpu, catalyst

I followed a tutorial to install the AMD catalyst for my GPU. When Ubuntu boots, all I can see is my desktop background. I can right click on it. Is there something I can do to fix this? Oh and the screen stays at a 800x600 resolution.

I used [this tutorial on Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930450) since I have integrated nvidia graphics but I use an AMD card:

- Card: AMD Radeon HD 7750 GDDR5 1GB.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using desktop (which looks like from the description), that tutorial was not for you. Hybrid chips are something different. Those are available only if you use some processor like i5/i7 where  graphics is built in with processor (not motherboard)  and mainly found in laptop to save power. The two graphics card are inter-connected (which is not in case of desktop, you connect monitor to either one of them)

Revert back what you did from  the following point, it should work fine.

`STEP 2 - Enabling, fixing the bug for direct rendering on the integrated card :`  in the tutorial.

OR

Remove all display driver (or perform a clean installation)

Use `Addtional drivers` in ubuntu to install the required driver.

Answer (score 0):

If you hit Ctrl + Alt + T

Then follow the steps found at http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Quantal_Installation_Guide#Removing_Catalyst.2Ffglrx

This will remove your proprietary drivers and revert back to the open source versions. May not be optimum, but it will most likely fix your problem.

...You could also follow the following steps for a temporary fix:
[http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Quantal_Installation_Guide#In_case_of_failure:](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Quantal_Installation_Guide#In_case_of_failure%3a)